# nginx: how to serve multiple site on same domain name without virtual hosting?

Tags: php-fpm, linode, drupal

I'm new of nginx.
I read some documentation to install it and configure it with drupal 8.

I have my server installed on linode. i access through ip address, not virtual host.

My drupal is located in var/www/html/d8/web.

So, to access my drupal site I type `ip-address/d8/web`.

if `root /var/www/html/d8/web` is in server default file it works well.
In this way I can't access other website in my server, every time I must change root directory in default file.

I tried with

```
location (d8/web/ {
 try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string
}
```

but, if root is an other directory, Nginx serves `index.php` in that directory.

The problem is I can't set server names, cause I work with ip address instead of virtual host. I access Linode from my Windows pc.

Some ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What is the reason for using IP addresses?

Comment: Go buy a domain name. They are cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you clearly need one different IP for each site, stating them in the `listen` clause of the each `server {}` block.